# what is the difference between matrix and float4x4 in HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl

When I define the `cBuffer` in `hlsl`, some examples shows

```
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
  matrix worldMatrix;
  matrix viewMatrix;
  matrix projectionMatrix;
};
```

And the other shows

```
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
  float4x4 worldMatrix;
  float4x4 viewMatrix;
  float4x4 projectionMatrix;
};
```

Does it means that type of matrix can have unlimited elements but float4x4 can just hold the first 16 elements?

which one do you prefer in HLSL?

Answer (score 4):

To support older DirectX 8 era HLSL programs, `matrix` by itself is a typedef for `matrix<float,4,4>`. BTW, `float4x4` is also a typedef for `matrix<float,4,4>`.

See [HLSL, User-Defined Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-user-defined)